# React: Can't export const

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to one line export const my `<SearchForm/>` but for some reason it's erroring out.

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';

export const SearchForm = props => (
  <form className="search-form" onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
    <input placeholder="Username" type="text" value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange}></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"></input>
  </form>)

SearchForm.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Home`.

It's fine if I do `const SearchForm = props => .....` and `export default <SearchForm/>` at the bottom. I've also tried `export default SearchForm...` and other variations.

I'm following an egghead.io tutorial and the guys using the exact same syntax so I have no idea what's wrong? Here's his code

[image]

Answer (score 18):

I guess you currently use

```
import SearchForm  from './SearchForm';
```

But because your export

```
export const SearchForm = props => (
```

So you must use this syntax

```
import {SearchForm} from './SearchForm';
```

To conclude:

When export default, import with no {}

When export without default, import with {}

Answer (score 0):

how did you import your component ?
You should try to add default after export:

```
export default class...
```

Comment: Your question on importing made me play around with it and managed to fix it. I was doing `import SearchForm from ...` and changed it to 'import {SearchForm} from...' and exported it with `export const SearchForm = props =>` ...

Comment: In reactjs you are "supposed" to declare only one component per file. So I thinks it's better to add the default keyword and remove the brackets in the import.

Comment: that would be my prefered option but it's saying unexpected token const.. not sure why

Comment: Have you tired to put class instead of const ?

Comment: I think export default const/var/let is invalid syntax

Comment: yep it's why I thinks it's cleaner to declare components as classes